# Откуда берется номер строки исключения в Java?

Tags: java, классы, исключения, jvm

К примеру, наш исходный код выполняет деление на ноль в строке *8*.
Если собрать *jar-файл* из этого кода и запустить - `ArithmeticException` опять скажет нам про строку 8 в нашем исходнике.

Получается, что в *.class*-файлах сохраняется даже форматирование исходника (*java*)? Или тут какой-то другой механизм?

Comment: Ну зачем же прямо форматирование. просто номера строк, сопоставленные с блоками кода где то сохраняются. Так многие компилируемые языки делают

Answer (score 9, accepted):

При компиляции по умолчанию добавляется номер строки в получаемый `byte-код`.

Можно настроить объем debug-информации, попадаемый в генерируемые файлы, с помощью [параметра компилятора `-g`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

```
-g:none                Без отладочной информации.
-g:lines               Только номера строк.
-g:lines,source        Номера строк и информация об исходном файле.
-g:lines,source,vars   Номера строк, информация об исходном файле и данные о локальных переменных.
-g                     То же самое, что и -g:lines,source,vars
```

Значение по умолчанию: `-g:lines,source`.